Issues when creating ImageMosaic from COGs in GeoServer
I'm trying to complete this tutorial because it best describes my use case for using GeoServer (to serve COGs and ImageMosaics of COGs stored in S3 thru GeoServer WMS) and I am encountering some errors.
The errors occur when supplying GeoServer with a prototype granule e.g.
curl -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" --write-out %{http_code} -d "https://modis-vi-nasa.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/MOD13A1.006/2018.01.01.tif" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/test/coveragestores/modisvi/remote.imagemosaic"

It seems like it can't create the sample image for some reason, and is failing in subsequent operations.
Suspicious lines of the logs when adding a prototype granule:
30 Jul. 12:22:55 INFO   [gce.imagemosaic] - Required key Levels not found.


Levels shouldn't be needed here

30 Jul. 12:22:56 DEBUG  [gce.imagemosaic] - Skipping invalid mosaic index table mod


The most suspicious is that one, how is it invalid? ...

30 Jul. 12:22:58 DEBUG  [referencing.factory] - Failure in the primary factory: No code "EPSG:4326" from authority "European Petroleum Survey Group" found for object of type "interface org.geotools.api.referencing.IdentifiedObject". Now trying the fallback factory...


Also suspicious...

30 Jul. 12:23:01 WARN   [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for path C:\GeoServer\data_dir\data\test\mod\sample_image


Probably just an error that a sample image was supposed to created automatically, but wasn't

Running GeoServer 2.25.0 on Windows 10, Java 11 and:
JNI GDAL Wrapper Version: 3.2.0
GDAL Version: 3.8.5
GDAL Release Date: 20240402
GDAL Build Info: PAM_ENABLED=YES
OGR_ENABLED=YES
CURL_ENABLED=YES
CURL_VERSION=8.7.0-DEV
GEOS_ENABLED=YES
GEOS_VERSION=3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0
PROJ_BUILD_VERSION=9.3.0
PROJ_RUNTIME_VERSION=9.3.0

ImageIO-Ext Version: 1.4.12

and:
PostgreSQL 16
PostGIS 3.4.2


Were you able to solve this? I am encountering nearly the exact same problem creating image mosaics with GeoTiffs on 2.25.3.
